# Communicating local server and remote server programmatically in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have an app that has been developed using java and play framework. i have build two app one for the local and one for the remote to view its report data online. Actually i want to synchronize local database with remote database. The question is, how can i communicate and response data between two server programmatically in thread.

Answer (score 0):

To communication between 2 PlayFramework Aps you can use standard REST WS on first App, and WS API on seccond one: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaWS

But, for operations on two databases you should consider using xa-transactions: https://dzone.com/articles/play-20-framework-and-xa

Comment: thank you @krysiek.. and is there any other proper way to sync postgresql schema only.